# How do I share my Internet connection over Wi-Fi from the command line?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

What is the command line that starts sharing the internet connection from LAN over Wi-Fi? I think it allows to set a specific network name and a password.

I remember it from some techie talk on a podcast, but they gave no specifics, and my friends told me it exists, though they couldn't remember it on the spot.

Comment: Why the requirement for it being command line only? Will normal [Internet Connection Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing) not work for you?

Comment: I'm only interested in the command line execution of this feature. I'm sure other people will find it interesting too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update

For some reason, this won't work in Windows 8:

> The hosted network couldn't be started.
>   The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

I have not found a solution to this problem. The answer remains valid for Windows 7, though.

---

This feature is called *hosted networks*.  On a Wi-Fi enabled computer running Windows 7, use the following commands in an elevated command prompt:

- `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=MODE ssid=SSID key=KEY keyusage=KEYUSAGE` 
  Changes access point settings.  `mode` can be `allow` or `disallow`, specifying whether the access point is enabled.  `ssid` is the name of the network; `key` is the encryption key used for accessing the network.  `keyusage` can be `persistent` or `temporary`, indicating whether the key is kept or discarded after one use (the default is `persistent`).  Note that WPA2-AES is used.
- `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` 
  Starts the access point.
- `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork` 
  Stops the access point.
- `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` 
  Shows the status of the access point.

To allow Internet access through the access point, open the properties for the adapter that provides the Internet connection under **Change adapter settings** in the **Network and Sharing Center**, then enable Internet Connection Sharing to the *Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter* that is providing the wireless connection, usually **Wireless Network Connection 2**.

Note that the access point created using this procedure uses infrastructure mode.  For more information and technical details about hosted networks, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.