# packet sniffing 3ds

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I am trying to packet sniff my 3DS just to see what information is available.

With Wireshark I noticed that I can only capture traffic which communicates with my computer directly, and not any device on my network.

So next I have used Cain and this allowed me to see some packets with Wireshark but this would not last long as the 3DS lost internet connectivity for a reason I don't understand since the use of Cain.

Is there a way to passively monitor the packets being sent between the 3DS and my router with Wireshark? I read about purchasing a pcap adapter and as I understand it, I plug this into my computer and then it will pick up all traffic for any devices on my network?

Comment: maybe cain does some arp trick? if you have a hub instead of a switch then you could. Besides a hub You also need the network card in promiscuous mode though i don't know how automatic that is.

Comment: If you're running a Windows 7 laptop, [this](http://superuser.com/a/580676) might help as the traffic will then pass through your computer.